# Session Sign in - Session string is null

Tags: asp.net

This is not working at all. I have done it many times but I don't know what's going wrong. the textbox always shows "not found" whereas it should be showing username.
Note: Textbox is just an example.

Login Page:

```
     protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();
        string username = email.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM MANAGER WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME AND PASSWORD=@PASSWORD";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", password.Text.Trim());
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["manager"] = username;
            Response.Redirect("ManagerHomePage.aspx");
            Session.RemoveAll();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Invalid Email or Password!";
        }
    }
```

ManagerHomePage.aspx :
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        if(Session["manager"]!=null)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Session["manager"].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "not found";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I removed Session.RemoveAll(), Session.Abandon(), Session.Clear() from the first 3 lines of Sign In Button and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ExecuteNonQuery` for `Select` command. `ExecuteNonQuery` is used for `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete` command. Try using `ExecuteReader`
Bellow is the code

```
protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    string username = email.Text.ToLower().Trim();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM MANAGER WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME AND PASSWORD=@PASSWORD";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", password.Text.Trim());
    SqlDataReader rdr=command.ExecuteReader();
    if(rdr.HasRows())
    {
        Session["manager"] = username;
        Response.Redirect("ManagerHomePage.aspx");
    }        
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Email or Password!";
    }
}
```